# How to filter rows of the embedded view in lotus notes?

Tags: view

I have placed an embedded view in a Form. This view is supposed to display all documents related to that form (Registration No.). I want the view rows to be filtered based on a key (Registration No.). I assume i have to write some lotus script code, as we normally do through lotus script by using like *view.GetAllDocumentsByKey("key",True)* but don't know how to do that for embedded view. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use LotusScript.

You need to use the "Show Single Category" option for the embedded view.

You also need to use the Registration No. as the first column of the view, and sort it Categorised, Ascending.

To be extra sure, add an extra character or two to the end of the Registration No (e.g. reg_Number + "##") and also add that to the formula for the Single Category when you embed the view.

This will prevent the view displaying documents for registration number 1234, when 123 is required.  This should not happen, but sometimes does, so the "##" is a useful delimiter to prevent it.

Look at the help document entitled "To show a single category in embedded views"